# Estimate number of combinations regarding translations and rotations

Tags: combinatorics

Let's suppose we have cube with $10\times 10\times 10=1000$ cells and $3$ red and $7$ blue balls.
The task is to estimate (at least roughly) the number of possible combinations excluding those which can be obtained by translation and rotation.

The number of ways to select $10$ $(7+3)$ cells out of $1000$ is $$\frac{1000!}{10!(1000-10)!} \approx 10^{23}$$
(combinations)

In the selected 10 cells 3 red and 7 blue balls can be put by
$$\frac{(3+7)!}{3!\times7!} = 120 \approx 10^2$$
(permutations with replacement)

Thus overall number of combinations is $10^{25}$. However, there are a lot of identical placement regarding translations and rotations. How to roughly estimate them?

UPDATE:

Taking into account comment of @shardulc there is $24$ rotational degrees of freedom. Then if $10$ balls occupy the most compact space $2\times2\times3$ it can be translated in $9\times9\times8 = 648$ ways. Thus overall there will be $648\times24 = 15552 \approx 10^4$ identical placements (upper estimate). So rough estimate of the number of possible placements of red and blue balls will be $10^{25}/10^4=10^{21}$. Is it correct?

Comment: What do you mean by translations? Do these wrap around the faces of the cube, or do you just shift arrangements within the cube in case there's enough space for that?

Comment: Just shift. I found similar questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481831/configurations-of-n-tiles-on-mxm-grid-up-to-rotation-translation. However I could not apply those consideration to my case.

Comment: Assuming the balls are not symmetrically placed (which they seldom will be), you have 24 possible orientations of the cube, and thus 24 rotationally identical placements. For translations, perhaps you can find the average number of shifts possible, since it depends in the spacing between the balls.

Comment: @shardulc, thanks. I edited my question and added some considerations based on your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of the cells are empty, the widths of the arrangement along the three directions are approximately independent and approximately the same as if $10$ balls were uniformly randomly distributed over $10$ bins. The expected margin of free cells in a given direction is

$$
\sum_{k=1}^9\left(1-\frac k{10}\right)^{10}\approx\frac12\;,
$$

so the two margins in one direction together have expected width roughly $1$. Thus there will be roughly $2^3=8$ translational equivalents of an arrangement on average, and as shardulc has pointed out $24$ rotations of the octahedral group (since symmetric arrangements with fewer rotational equivalents are rare), so a rough estimate of the number of inequivalent arrangements would be

$$
\frac{\binom{1000}{10}\binom{10}3}{24\cdot8}\approx1.65\cdot10^{23}\;.
$$

Comment: Nice suggestion! I would like to completely understand the first equation. It looks like the probabilistic estimate, however, it returns the number of the free cells. Could you describe the logic behind this equations? What do numbers 10 mean in denominator and power?

Comment: @DrDom: The summand is the probability that the left-most $k$ cells are empty. The denominator is the number of cells along one direction. The exponent is the number of balls. The probability for one ball not to be in the left-most $k$ cells is $1-\frac k{10}$, and the probability for none of them to be there is the $10$-th power of that. Summing these probabilities yields the expected number of free cells (since the case with $n$ free cells contributes to the sum $n$ times).

Comment: I agree with your final estimate $10^{23}$, it looks reasonable, because I clearly overestimated the number of possible translations.(see UPDATE). However summation of probabilities is somewhat questionable. How to make the step from probability to the number? At `k=1` the probability that 1 left-most cell is empty is 0.35, at `k=2` is 0.107 and so on. Summing these values we obtain probability of 1 left-most cell is empty OR 2 left-most cells are empty OR ... and so on.

Comment: @DrDom: No -- that would be the case if the possibilities were mutually exclusive. Here they are the opposite, fully inclusive: If the left-most $3$ cells are empty, then also the left-most $2$ cells are empty and the left-most $1$ cell is empty. Thus this event is counted $3$ times, which is exactly what we want to get the expected number of free cells. More formally,

$$
\mathbb E(k)=\sum_kk(p_k-p_{k+1})=\sum_kp_k+\sum_k(kp_k-(k+1)p_{k+1})=\sum_kp_k\;,
$$

where $p_k$ is the probability that *at least* $k$ cells are free and $p_k-p_{k+1}$ is the probability that *exactly* $k$ cells are free.